# saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile() giving error when used as output format

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running a modified version of the teragen program in Spark, written in Scala. I am trying to save the output file using the function saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(). The relevant code is given below:

```
dataset.map(row => (NullWritable.get(), new BytesWritable(row))).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(output)
```

The code is compiling successfully. However, when running it, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: class scala.runtime.Nothing$ not org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setClass(Configuration.java:1794)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.setOutputFormatClass(Job.java:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:811)
    at GenSort$.main(GenSort.scala:52)
    at GenSort.main(GenSort.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Is there a way to make it work with saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile()? I would be glad for any help.

Comment: which version of Hadoop are you running?

Comment: did you try to implicitly specify output format?

Answer (score 1):

The `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile` expect key, value, outformat classes.

**Method signature is:**

```
saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(path: String,suffix: String, 
 keyClass: Class[_],
 valueClass: Class[_], 
 outputFormatClass: Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat[_, _]])
```

**Implementation should be:**

```
dataset.map(row => (NullWritable.get(), new BytesWritable(row))).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("hdfs:\\.....","<suffix>",classOf[NullWritable],classOf[BytesWritable],classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat[NullWritable, BytesWritable]]))
```

or

```
dataset.map(row => (NullWritable.get(), new BytesWritable(row))).
saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("hdfs:\\.....","<suffix>",
new NullWritable().getClass,new BytesWritable.getClass,
new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat[NullWritable, BytesWritable].getClass))
```