# Getting Hadoop OutputFormat RunTimeException while running Apache Spark Kafka Stream

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am running a program which uses Apache Spark to get get data from Apache Kafka cluster and puts the data in a Hadoop file. My program is below:

```
public final class SparkKafkaConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
        Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] topics = "Topic1, Topic2, Topic3".split(",");
        for (String topic: topics) {
            topicMap.put(topic, 3);
        }
        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
                KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, "kafka.test.com:2181", "NameConsumer", topicMap);
        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                return tuple2._2();
            }
        });
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                return Lists.newArrayList(",".split(x));
            }
        });
        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
                    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
                    }
                }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                    public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                        return i1 + i2;
                    }
                });
        wordCounts.print();
        wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/spark/stream/", "txt");
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

I am using the this command to submit the application: `C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2 --class "SparkKafkaConsumer" --master local[4] target\simple-project-1.0.jar`

I am getting this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: class scala.runtime.Nothing$ not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setClass(Configuration.java:2148)`

What is causing this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: This looks like an issue in Spark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007085/saveasnewapihadoopfile-giving-error-when-used-as-output-format ..

Comment: Could you try `saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/spark/stream/", "txt", Text.class, IntWritable.class, TextOutputFormat.class)` instead ?

Comment: @Hawknight What is the full package of `Text.class` and `TextOutputFormat.class`?

Comment: `Text` comes from `org.apache.hadoop.io` and `TextOutputFormat` comes from `org.apache.hadoop.mapred`

Comment: @Hawknight That solved it. Thanks! You should add this as an answer.

Comment: Great, I'll put it as an answer then !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the error is not really evocative, but it is usually better to specify the format of the data you want to output in any of the `saveAsHadoopFile` methods to protect yourself from this type of exception.

Here's the prototype of your particular method in the documentation :

```
saveAsHadoopFiles(java.lang.String prefix, java.lang.String suffix, java.lang.Class<?> keyClass, java.lang.Class<?> valueClass, java.lang.Class<F> outputFormatClass)
```

In your example, that would correspond to :

```
wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/spark/stream/", "txt", Text.class, IntWritable.class, TextOutputFormat.class)
```

Based on the format of your `wordCounts` PairDStream, I chose `Text` as the key is of type `String`, and `IntWritable` as the value associated to the key is of type `Integer`.

Use `TextOutputFormat` if you just want basic plain text files, but you can look into the subclasses of `FileOutputFormat` for more output options.

As this was also asked, the `Text` class comes from the `org.apache.hadoop.io` package and the `TextOutputFormat` comes from the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` package.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness (@Jonathan gave the right answer )

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

...
wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/spark/stream/", "txt", Text.class, IntWritable.class, TextOutputFormat.class)
```